# Laravel routing: static text in optional url segment

Tags: php, url, laravel-4

I'm migrating the forum section of my website to Laravel 4. I manage the pagination myself. (Not the Laravel built-in one)

My urls currently use the following format:

```
example.com/forum
example.com/forum/page-1
```

I'd like to keep it like that after the migration.

My route looks like that:

```
Route::get('/forum/page-{page?}',
    array('uses' => 'ForumController@showForum', 'as' => 'forum'));
```

But of course it doesn't work when I request the page without a page number.

I can do it like `/forum/{pagetext?}-{page?}` but I dont want to have to catch the pagetext parameter in my Controller, and I want to only give the $page parameter when I build urls for the page with URL::route().

I've found many examples on Internet but it was always with multiple parameters, no static optional text.

How can I make this "static" portion optional as well ?

I'm thinking to something like an optional group in a regular expression, like `/forum/(page-{page})?` but how do I do that in Laravel ?

Comment: Why do you want it to be optional then? You can have `forum` url as 1 route, and `forum/page-{page}` as another, both using the same controller (method) if you want.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I've thought to this at the start but forgot. Thanks for mentioning it. It gives the impression to have two routes but that's the very same one, so that doesn't look totally nice for me. But it looks like a very good approach to have clean parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly need the parameter to be optional, I would make the whole segment of that route a single parameter, and you can use a regular expression to enforce it:

```
Route::get('/forum/{page?}', function($page = null) {
    echo 'On page ' . $page;
})->where('page', 'page-[\d]+');
```

The drawback here is you'll have to get the numeric page number from within your route.

As @Jarek mentioned in the comments, you can also split this up into two different routes:

```
Route::get('/forum', function() {
    echo 'Forum Index';
});

Route::get('/forum/page-{page}', function($page) {
    echo 'On page ' . $page;
})->where('page', '[\d]+');
```

Comment: If theres no way to do it "natively" in Laravel (without further manipulating parameters content), @Jarek solution looks like a clean solution. I just miss the possibility to call them both with the same route name, and passing a null or number of page to do the switch between them.